# ESLint: Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body. (arrow-body-style)

Tags: javascript, eslint

This rule, triggered by the below snippet of code, is most confusing (to me - and others it appears). If I remove the curlies, it breaks. If I add parens around the block, it breaks. What to do?

```
const MainLayout = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="main">
      <Header />
      <Navbar />
      <Content>
        {props.children}
      </Content>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is ESLint v4.13.1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you're just returning a value immediately, you don't need a `return` statement in an arrow function. Just put the value directly after the arrow.

And when there's just a single argument, you don't need parentheses around the argument list.

```
const MainLayout = props => (
    <div className="main">
      <Header />
      <Navbar />
      <Content>
        {props.children}
      </Content>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: And that then gives: `Unexpected parentheses around single function argument having a body with no curly braces (arrow-parens)`

Comment: Then get rid of the parentheses.

Comment: And that then gives: `Missing parentheses around multilines JSX (react/jsx-wrap-multilines)`

Comment: Only remove the parentheses around `props`, not the JSX. I think you may have picked up an intermediate edit that was wrong.

Comment: All the above solution are not fruitful still having the error .

Comment: @thinkerBOB ESLint warnings are not errors, the code should still run.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need **retun** just add **(** instead of **{** .
Like this...

```
const Card = props => (
  <View style={styles.containerStyle}>{props.children}</View>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Babel Extension]

Remove the above extension from your VS Code editor issue will be soved