# Eslint Error - Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the =>

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I am getting the error  Failed to Compile `Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the =>`

File:

```
{
    this.state.items.map((item) => {
       return (
         <div key={item}>
             <a href={item.mainContact.phoneHref + item.mainContact.phone}>
                <i className="fa fa-phone" />
                <strong>{item.mainContact.phone}</strong>
              </a>
          </div>
        );
    })
}
```

Anyone who could help me understand the error that would be great.

Thank you

**Update**

My .eslintrc.json file:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": ["airbnb"],
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
      "class-methods-use-this": 0,
      "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
          "error",
          {
            "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
          }
      ]
  }
}
```

Here is my devDependencies from package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
  "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
  "eslint": "^5.6.1",
  "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
  "eslint-loader": "^2.1.1",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
  "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
  "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
  "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
  "react-transition-group": "^2.4.0",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.1.1"
},
```

Comment: show us your eslint configuration please

Comment: updated  question. thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ESLint: Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body. (arrow-body-style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019945/eslint-unexpected-block-statement-surrounding-arrow-body-arrow-body-style)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you use arrow functions you have two syntax options when returning values:

> 1. () => { return something }
> 2. () => expression

In the second case you just write expression that is automatically returned. The [eslint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style) that is giving you the error is telling you that if you have just one expression you can remove the curly braces and return the expression directly like this:

```
{
    this.state.items.map((item) => (
         <div key={item}>
             <a href={item.mainContact.phoneHref + item.mainContact.phone}>
                <i className="fa fa-phone" />
                <strong>{item.mainContact.phone}</strong>
              </a>
          </div>
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply remove your **return()** function and put whole block into function
like this

```
{
    this.state.items.map((item) => (
         <div key={item}>DATA</div>
    )
}
```

**Here is examples how it work:**

```
() => { return <div key={item}>DATA</div>}
```

so after remove our return function it will work like that

```
() => (<div key={item}>DATA</div>)
```

or

```
() => yourState
```

Answer (score 6):

Add the below code :

```
"arrow-body-style": "off"
```

Answer (score 5):

you're using airbnb eslint preset

that enforces that arrow functions do not use braces if you just return one object.

Change your code to this and it should compile

```
this.state.items.map((item) => (<div key={item}>
     <a href={item.mainContact.phoneHref + item.mainContact.phone}>
        <i className="fa fa-phone" />
        <strong>{item.mainContact.phone}</strong>
      </a>
  </div>)
)
```

[See docs for that rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style)

[See where is configured in the airbnb repo](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/d951220399c75099838fc79577033b00530b2b90/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/es6.js#L18)

Answer (score 2):

The rule is saying that you can remove the curly braces along with the "return" surrounding the  that you're returning. However, returning a if statement would require the curly braces.

This is the correct solution to your question based on the lint error:

```
{
    this.state.items.map((item) => (
         <div key={item}>
             <a href={item.mainContact.phoneHref + item.mainContact.phone}>
                <i className="fa fa-phone" />
                <strong>{item.mainContact.phone}</strong>
              </a>
          </div>
        )
    );
}
```

The curly braces would however be needed if you were returning multiple expressions. Here's a example using a if statement:

```
{
    this.state.items.map((item) => {
      if (!item.mainContact.phone) {
        return (
          <div key={item}>
            <span>n/a</span>
          </div>
        )
      }
      return (
        <div key={item}>
            <a href={item.mainContact.phoneHref + item.mainContact.phone}>
               <i className="fa fa-phone" />
               <strong>{item.mainContact.phone}</strong>
             </a>
         </div>
      );
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this:

```
const myFunction = (func) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    func(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
};
```

As this:

```
const myFunction = (func) => (req, res, next) =>
  func(req, res, next).catch(next);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Babel Extension]

If you have Babel installed in your extension then uninstallation of this extension will resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when i was returning a json directly using map

```js
const Containers = Sales.results.map((value) => {
    return { date: value[0], sale: value[1] };
});
```

I had to change the way i returned my json , I used an variable to hold on to results and then return the variable which solved the issue here is later fix code:

```js
const Containers = Sales.results.map((value) => {
    const finalTrends = { date: value[0], sale: value[1] };
    return finalTrends;
  });
```