# Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the => arrow-body-style

Tags: javascript, eslint

My code is here:

```
   await page.evaluate(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 60000));
});
```

What should I remove in this line?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eslint Error - Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the =>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52636910/eslint-error-unexpected-block-statement-surrounding-arrow-body-move-the-retur)

Comment: @RafaelTavares almost same, but our code not doing same thing, anyway, Thanks dude!

Comment: It's doing _exactly_ the same thing, as far as this context is concerned; it's immediately returning a value in an arrow function body. Put it this way: do you think SO needs a separate Q&A pair for the same ESLint error with every possible _value_ being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript arrow functions you can return something by writing just a single expression

```js
await page.evaluate(() => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 60000)));
```

Comment: _"array"_ -> arrow?

Comment: @kissu Ofcourse it looks because that's the only way to write it :D

Answer (score 2):

```
await page.evaluate(() => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 60000)));
```